# Calling R script from Python does not save log file in version 4

Tags: python, r, subprocess

I am calling from python an R script that is very simple called *R Code.R*:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
print(args)
source(args[1])

setwd("<YOUR PATH>")
output <- head(mtcars, n = n)
write.table(output, "output.txt")
```

using the following script:

```
import subprocess

pth = "<YOUR PATH>"


subprocess.call(" ".join(["C:/R/R-3.6.0/bin/x64/R.exe", "-f", '"' + pth + '/R Code.R"', "--args", 
                '"' + pth + '/arguments.txt"',"1>", '"' + pth + '/log.txt"', "2>&1"]))


subprocess.call(" ".join(["C:/R/R-4.0.3/bin/x64/R.exe", "-f", '"' + pth + '/R Code.R"', "--args", 
                '"' + pth + '/arguments.txt"',"1>", '"' + pth + '/log.txt"', "2>&1"]))
```

where *arguments.txt* contain:
n <- 10

The problem is that when I am using R-4.0.3 the log.txt file is not generating and I need to dump a log file because it is automatically looking for it in a posterior process I have.

When I am executing in CMD (Windows) the following command:

```
C:/R/R-4.0.3/bin/x64/R.exe -f "<YOUR PATH>/R Code.R" --args "<YOUR PATH>/arguments.txt" 1> "<YOUR PATH>/log.txt" 2>&1'
```

It does work perfectly, it is only when embedded in another software.

Also, I have tried without white space in the name and calling the scripts from root folder without having to specify the path.
Any idea of why it doesn't work for R-4.* or even better, how to solve it?

Thank you!

PD: Thank you, Martin, for your tips and for making me formulate a better question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rhelp people got this solved, thank you, *Duncan Murdoch*!

Solution 1:

```
import os
pth = "<YOUR PATH>"
os.system(" ".join(["C:/R/R-4.0.3/bin/x64/R.exe", "-f", '"' + pth + '/RCode.R"', "--args", 
                '"' + pth + '/arguments.txt"',"1>", '"' + pth + '/log.txt"']))
```

Solution 2:

```
import subprocess
pth = "<YOUR PATH>"
subprocess.call(" ".join(["1>", '"' + pth + '/log.txt"', "2>&1",
                          "C:/R/R-4.0.3/bin/x64/R.exe", "-f", '"' + pth + '/RCode.R"', "--args", 
                '"' + pth + '/arguments.txt"']), shell = True)
```

Answer (score 2):

well, in one case (3.6.0) you use `R.exe` , in the other (4.0.3) `Rscript.exe`.
Both R and Rscript have existed for a long time, and they have always had slightly different behavior.

You really should not confuse them with each other (even though, on Windows, I see, they look like the same file .. they will *not* behave the same).

Ok, now you use `R.exe` for both.
Just to find out more / see more where the problem may happen, can you try
all of

1. using a *minimal* reproducible example, i.e. one we can use directly ourselves, i.e., not using  `"<YOUR PATH>"` (nor `setwd(.)`)
2. *not* using file names with a `' '` (space), i.e., e.g.,  use `code.R`
3. calling this from a "terminal"/shell instead of as python subprocess ?

Last but not least: Yes, for R 4.0.0, a completely updated toolset ("brandnew toolchain", e.g. much newer C compiler) was used to build R for windows, "Rtools 4.0" or `rtools40`:  https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ . So changes are expected  but should typically only have been to the better, not the worse ..

Comment: You are completely right that they are different in the example but I have tried as well with both as R.exe and it is the same behaviour. Apologies, I have edited now the question since it is true that it can lead to confusion

Comment: Thank you Martin, very curiously for one of your points, it works when executed directly on the cmd! but when we call the script embedded on another language it does not... we tried with other software apart from Python and does not work either.